# Run the Arch ISO in VirtualBox with shared folders

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to use the shared folders feature when running the Arch ISO as a VirtualBox guest OS. The reason is that in the shared folder I have the scripts to make my persistent setup.

After the Arch ISO bootstrap, I run:

```
pacman -Syu virtualbox-guest-utils
```

Everything seems smooth but when I load VirtualBox modules:

```
modprobe -a vboxguest vboxsf vboxvideo #Following guide here: vboxsf only might do
```

it gives an error. I know that I can fix it creating the dependency file:

```
depmod 3.16.1-1-ARCH
```

The version is that from `uname -r` and I get an error again, as there is no directory:

```
/lib/modules/3.16.1-1-ARCH
```

The previous `pacman -Syu ...` has updated the kernel and therefore I have now a `3.16.2-1-ARCH` directory. In fact:

```
depmod 3.16.2-1-ARCH
```

works, but  `modprobe` keeps not working.

I assume that this is due to the mismatch between the `uname -r` and the updated kernel. Reading around it is suggested to reboot, but in my case I will lose everything since I am running from an ISO.

I reboot an try to install the guest additions without updating, using the last Arch ISO available:

```
pacman -Sy virtualbox-guest-utils # now no -u
```

but I know that this is a bad practice! Anyway I run:

```
depmod 3.16.1-1-ARCH # non-updated kernel!
modprobe -a vboxguest vboxsf vboxvideo
mount.vboxsf arch /mnt
ls /mnt
```

and I can finally see my shared files.

This process was a kind of lucky trial and error.
Can you tell me which is the best practice to accomplish this? That is installing the VirtualBox guest additions in a volatile environment (the Arch ISO).

Comment: Well, you figured it out by yourself: Do not update the kernel if you cant reboot. Btw, it's not bad practice to run simply `pacman -S <package>`. You don't always have to update your entire system (and neither updated the database) just to install a poop.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is subjective but there are a couple of them:

1. Make your own ISO already containing the VBox modules for the included kernel. (See [[1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Remastering_the_Install_ISO)], [[2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Archiso)], or [[3](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Archboot)].) This might generally be the preferred option if you can and if you're going to use it a lot, but if you're only going to use it once it might be considered a bit of a waste of time.
2. Upload the scripts to a pastebin or file host site instead, or even just run a simple HTTP server on your host, and download them inside the virtual machine. `darkhttpd` is one simple HTTP server that is under 100KiB big and you just execute it giving it the path to the directory to serve over HTTP, and might be the easiest and preferred for more one-off things like in your case.
3. Or just do what you did. It works in a lot of cases, but you should do your best to avoid it because it could break. Never do this outside the installation medium.

Comment: Currently I am moving to FTP server on host + curlftpfs on guest.
The workaround I found in my question depends on the kernel version, so sometimes it is  unavoidable to restart the system. If you can give (the scratch of)  a script to generate an Arch-for-VirtualBox ISO, it will be nice.

Comment: @antonio, I don't have any scripts, but I linked to three different ways to make a custom ISO, no script is really necessary, instead you probably want a custom archiso profile.